# how update jtable? realize setValueAt?

Tags: swing

So i create method in MytableModel

```
public void removeRow(int row) {

            if (getSelectedUser(row) != null) {
                Authorisation.userMap.remove(getSelectedUser(row).getName());
                list.remove(getSelectedUser(row));
                System.out.println(list);
                Registration.writeToFile();
            }

            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }
```

then in outer class i create method

```
public void deleteFromTable() {

        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = usersTable.getSelectedRow();
                model.removeRow(index);
            }
        });
    }
```

and in other class invoked as

```
AdminFrame af = new AdminFrame(frame);
af.deleteFromTable();
```

Before that selected row deleted from ArrayList and table not update. WHATS WRONG?

Comment: something wrong with the code you are not showing (best in the form of a SSCCE)

Answer (score 0):

> When I delete a row from the table, so I delete the record from ArrayList,

All updates should be done to the TableModel. So you need to create a method like removeRow(....) in your TableModel. This method will do two things:

1. remove the data from your ArrayList
2. invoke fireTableRowsDeleted(...)

Or an easier way is to use the `Row Table Model` which does most of the code for you. All you need to do is extend the class to implement the getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods as demonstrated by the `JButtonTableModel.java` example.

Even if you decide not to use the RowTableModel it will give you an idea of how to implement the removeRow(...) method in your TableModel

Comment: @SorcerOK, you tried what? If you did as I suggested above then it would work. Whatever you did you didn't do it properly. You still haven't posted your `SSCCE`, so we really can't help because we would just be making guesses.

Comment: create method removeRow(int rowindex) - row index=getSelectedRow. use fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex). But data from arrayList deleted and table not update. Whats wrong?

Comment: Well, I made a type. It should be `fireTableRowsDeleted(...)`. If that doesn't help, then for the 3rd time you haven't posted a `SSCCE` so we can't help!!! Don't reply without posting a SSCCE.

Comment: I present above as I do.WHATS WRONG?